# How to loop through a question Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am new to Microsoft service and already built my QnAMaker by feeding it an excel file which contains questions and answers. After publishing the QnA Maker, I downloaded the code and tested it on a Bot Framework Emulator. The file contains product names as the answer and the product description as question. When the user gives a description of the product and if it matches one of the description in the file, the product name will be generated as answer.
The bot ask the user to give some details about the product and afterwards it looks for some keywords which trigger an answer from the QnA. But if the bot could not find any answer, I want it to ask the user again (at least 3 times) and if nothing after three times, it should just say 'sorry...'.

Could anyone please guide me how can I do the looping part. Should it be done in the code?

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialog
{
/// <summary>
/// QnAMaker action builder class
/// </summary>
public class QnAMakerBaseDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    // Dialog Options parameters
    public const string DefaultNoAnswer = "Sorry, I couldn't find any 
match. Could you please give me more details?";
    public const string DefaultCardTitle = "Did you mean:";
    public const string DefaultCardNoMatchText = "None of the 
above.";
    public const string DefaultCardNoMatchResponse = "Thanks for the 
feedback.";

    private readonly IBotServices _services;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see 
cref="QnAMakerBaseDialog"/> class.
    /// Dialog helper to generate dialogs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">Bot Services.</param>
    public QnAMakerBaseDialog(IBotServices services, IConfiguration 
configuration) : base()
    {
        this._services = services;
        this._configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected async override Task<IQnAMakerClient> 
GetQnAMakerClientAsync(DialogContext dc)
    {
        return this._services?.QnAMakerService;
    }

    protected override Task<QnAMakerOptions> 
GetQnAMakerOptionsAsync(DialogContext dc)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new QnAMakerOptions
        {
            ScoreThreshold = DefaultThreshold,
            Top = DefaultTopN,
            QnAId = 0,
            RankerType = "Default",
            IsTest = false
        });
    }

    protected async override Task<QnADialogResponseOptions> 
GetQnAResponseOptionsAsync(DialogContext dc)
    {
        var noAnswer = (Activity)Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        noAnswer.Text = this._configuration["DefaultAnswer"] ?? 
 DefaultNoAnswer;

        var cardNoMatchResponse = 
 (Activity)MessageFactory.Text(DefaultCardNoMatchResponse);

        var responseOptions = new QnADialogResponseOptions
        {
            ActiveLearningCardTitle = DefaultCardTitle,
            CardNoMatchText = DefaultCardNoMatchText,
            NoAnswer = noAnswer,
            CardNoMatchResponse = cardNoMatchResponse,
        };

        return responseOptions;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure what issue you are facing and what you have tried, Go through the concept of dialog prompt and waterfall dialog in bot framework. Based on the situation you can use this dialogs in chatbot.

Comment: So first I created a KB in QnAMaker including multi-turn conversations. Then I published and downloaded the source code in C#. There is a question which i created in my KB which ask the user to give some description of the product he/she is looking for. If a match is found, the bot will give the result. But if the bot couldn't find any match, I want it to ask the user to give more details. Right now the bot keeps saying that it cannot find a match over and over when the user inputs something wrong. I want it to stop after 3 tries. Where should I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how your bot is set up, but in general yes you would do this in your code. Every time QnA Maker returns the default answer, you can increment a state variable (conversation state makes the most sense). Then have a condition on your output activity that if your "noAnswer" variable > 3 then perform some other action. If you can show some of your specific code I may be able to help you put something together specific to your design.

Comment: Sadly I am using both nodejs and I believe an older approach to Q&A. This is quite different from my implementation. I can try to provide some guidance based on my approach in an answer but it will not be a 1:1 solution with your application.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a slightly different approach to Q&A, plus I am using nodejs, so this might not be 100% applicable to you, but it is the approach I would use to this type of functionality so hopefully it will be helpful to you or others trying to accomplish the same thing.

The general algorithm, with added state tracking, is this:

1. Query the QnA Maker service with the input activity
2. Check the confidence score of the answer
3. If the score is above threshold, reset the "no answer counter" and send activity with the answer (or return it to the root dialog)
4. If the score is below threshold, increment the "no answer counter". If the "no answer counter" is below threshold, reprompt the user. If the "no answer counter" is above threshold, reply with the "sorry..." message.

Here is how I would implement this in nodejs. In my case I am returning only the answer activity to a root dialog. But it looks like you have DialogContext passed in your QnAMakerDialog so you could send the activity directly. You do need to make sure you have your conversationState object passed to the dialog, which I have assumed and named `conversationState` and `dialogState` for the state object and state accessor respectively.

```js
const conversationData = await this.dialogState.get(dc, {});
var outputActivity = null;
var repromptAnswer = `Text or card if no answer found`
var defaultAnswer = `Text or card if no answer found after threshold met`
var qnaResult = await QnAServiceHelper.queryQnAService(context.activity.text, oldState);
if (qnaResult[0].score > MINIMUM_SCORE) {
  outputActivity = MessageFactory.text(qnaAnswer);
  conversationData.noAnswerCounter = 0;
} else {
  conversationData.noAnswerCounter = conversationData.noAnswerCounter+1 || 1;
  if (conversationData.noAnswerCounter <= 3) {
    outputActivity = repromptAnswer;
  } else {
    outputActivity = defaultAnswer;
}
await this.conversationState.saveChanges(dc);
return outputActivity;
```